# Cosmos DB Javascript stored procedure - bug?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I've been observing some strange behaviour in a stored procedure in Azure Cosmos DB using javascript API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#javascript-language-integrated-query-api)

Assuming there is a document in the database with the body.id = '---' the procedure below correctly return that document. However, if I comment the line 'return found ' and uncomment the lines with 'if (1==1)' then the stored procedure returns an empty result. I tried changing it to if (found){return found;} else{return false;}' - same empty output. Also, same happens if I write 'found = found && (1==1);' after 'let found = c.body.id != null && c.body.id ==t;'

Is this a Javascript bug or me doing something wrong?

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample() {
    __.filter(c=>{
        //return true;
        let t = "---";

        let found = c.body.id != null && c.body.id ==t;


  return found; <---
    //if (1==1){
    //    return found;
    //}

}
, {pageSize: -1}, 

    (a, b, c)=>{

        __.response.setBody(b);
            return;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your issue on my side.

> The following JavaScript constructs do not get optimized for Azure
>   Cosmos DB indices:
>
> Control flow (for example, if, for, while) Function calls

Based on the statement in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#javascript-language-integrated-query-api), if is not recommanded to use in `predicateFunction`.

You could just filter documents by `return expression(e.g. x.isMetadata === true);`

Comment: Basically, got enough examples to convince myself that Javascript inside Cosmos DB is extremely unreliable.

 let found = c.body.id != null && c.body.id.toLowerCase() ==t; <-- this doesn't work, always returns empty set of documents

However, this works and correctly finds the document (although it doesnt make sense): 
 let found = c.body.id != null && c.body.id ==t && c.body.id.toLowerCase() ==t;

Comment: Leaving alone optimisation and performance, I cannot understand why in my first example when I do anything with the variable 'found' , the filter stops working. I tried declaring it as const found = ...  and then writing 'if (found) return true else return false' -  still getting the same weird behavior.

Comment: @ValeryGavrilov  You could add feedback here to ask for more statements : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db